# How do I add the output from a function to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been encountering this problem a few times. How to add the output from a function, rather than the function itself to an array in JavaScript. Consider the following:

```
function getRandomValue(){
  returns a random number
}

myArray = [getRandomValue(), getRandomValue()];
```

Is it possible to add just the random numbers and not the function itself to the array?

Comment: What you have *does* populate the array with the return values of `getRandomValue`.

Comment: yup, you're adding the **result** of the function...

Comment: getRandomValue() is a function call
getRandomValue — is function reference
So, very simplified explanation:
`[getRandomValue(), getRandomValue()]` at the first, getRandomValue function is called, it will return some random number:
e.g.  `[5, 3]` and after that it will assign to your array.

Comment: My example might be a bit too simple. Would an ambiguous reference to _self_ or _this_ be a problem later or is the function output evaluated at the time I created the array?

Comment: It's evaluated when you create your array. So there is no problem.

Comment: Ok, my problem lies elsewhere. Thanks for the discussion :D

Comment: @JamesAllardice or Maxwell should answer, so that the question could have an accepted answer and be cleaner.

Comment: @dystroy - I have answered, but not sure if it will make it any cleaner really! Cleanest would probably be a deleted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have *already does* populate the array with the return values of the function:

```
function getRandomValue(){
    //returns a random number
}

var myArray = [getRandomValue(), getRandomValue()]; // Call the function
var myArray2 = [getRandomValue, getRandomValue]; // Reference to the function
```

The parentheses following the identifier cause the function to be invoked, and the return value of it will be placed at the appropriate index of the array.

Were you to remove the invoking parentheses as shown above, you would be populating your array with references to the function, rather than the values returned by it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables.

```
var a = getRandomValue();
var b = getRandomValue();
myArray = [a,b];
```

However, as said in comments, when you call the function in the array, you put the result in the array, not the function itself. So you have exactly the same behavior as with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:
just put it into a loop if you want more then one values.**

```
var myArray= [];
console.log(myArray.push(Math.random()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to use the array_push function:

```
myarray.push(getRandomValue());
```

Comment: There is no such function in JavaScript.

Comment: this is php, not javascript....

Comment: Sorry you are right. I've been using PHP too much of late so I confused the two.
The correct function is array.push - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

I have corrected the code